# Remove default language from front page url

Tags: i18n-l10n, uri

I have a drupal 7 site which was originally set up in English. The home page url would display www.mysite.com and other languages with /es /de /it after the url.

After changing the default language to Spanish, my home page url now displays www.mysite.com/es. How can I remove the trailing language from the home page while maintaining all other content like this:

www.mysite.com

www.mysite.com/es/more/content

www.mysite.com/en/more/content

I've tried removing the es from the Path prefix language code but that removes /es from all content which I need to maintain old urls which I migrated.